# Google API: Find a Users YouTube Channel

Tags: oauth, youtube, youtube-api

I was using the YouTube API and was trying to get a user's YouTube Link.  The only thing that shows up is the Google+ link as a field called link.  Is there anyway to get the users's Youtube information from the Google Account info?

The Google Response has first_name,given_name, and link in the json response.

Thanks!

Comment: Your question would be a lot clearer if you could provide details about the API call you're making, a sample of the response you're getting back, and an explanation (including an example) of what you mean by a "user's YouTube Link".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know if it's exactly what you want, but using the Google+ API you can get the user urls and one of them can be the user YouTube channel url

More info:
https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get

Example:

Request:

> https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/117629885563933382879?key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Response:

```
{
 "kind": "plus#person",
 "etag": "\"l9gWq2lTiBDNZWBx8kpM7h7VNYs/as5084EFycaxtFP9IxDLvhbwZKM\"",
 "birthday": "0000-12-30",
 "gender": "male",
 "urls": [
  {
   "value": "http://twitter.com/matiasmolinas",
   "type": "other"
  },
  {
   "value": "http://gplus.to/matiasmolinas",
   "type": "other"
  },
  {
   "value": "http://ar.linkedin.com/in/matiasmolinas",
   "type": "other"
  },
  {
   "value": "https://www.facebook.com/matias.molinas",
   "type": "other"
  },
  {
   "value": "http://www.youtube.com/user/matiasmolinasvideo",
   "type": "other"
  },
  {
   "value": "http://stackoverflow.com/users/1427200/matias-molinas",
   "type": "other"
  },
  {
   "value": "http://santafegtug.blogspot.com/",
   "type": "other"
  },
  {
   "value": "http://fuse21.blogspot.com/",
   "type": "other"
  },
  {
   "value": "http://lookthiscode.blogspot.com.ar/",
   "type": "other"
  },
  {
   "value": "https://yt-topic-explorer.googlecode.com/git/dist/index.html",
   "type": "other"
  },
  {
   "value": "http://santafegtug.appspot.com/",
   "type": "other"
  }
 ],
 "objectType": "person",
 "id": "117629885563933382879",
 "displayName": "Matias Molinas",
 "name": {
  "familyName": "Molinas",
  "givenName": "Matias"
 },
 "aboutMe": "Citas favoritas:<br /><br />Dentro de veinte años te sentirás más desilusionado por las cosas que no hiciste que por aquéllas que hiciste. Así que suelta las amarras. Navega fuera de la bahía segura. Atrapa los alisios en tus velas. Explora. Sueña. Descubre.<br />",
 "url": "https://plus.google.com/117629885563933382879",
 "image": {
  "url": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-AJKFDGod6us/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAD64/Olccnle-qH4/photo.jpg?sz=50"
 },
 "organizations": [
  {
   "name": "UNER",
   "title": "Bioingenieria",
   "type": "school",
   "primary": false
  },
  {
   "name": "Software Consultant",
   "title": "Software Consultant",
   "type": "work",
   "startDate": "2011",
   "endDate": "2011",
   "primary": true
  },
  {
   "name": "Software Santa Fe",
   "type": "work",
   "endDate": "2011",
   "primary": false
  }
 ],
 "placesLived": [
  {
   "value": "Santa Fe, Argentina",
   "primary": true
  }
 ],
 "isPlusUser": true,
 "verified": false,
 "cover": {
  "layout": "banner",
  "coverPhoto": {
   "url": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-DjGbmNDlV3U/UNCgpGJu_WI/AAAAAAAAD7Q/7Uk2WidwxnI/w940-h428/gdesummit.png",
   "height": 428,
   "width": 940
  },
  "coverInfo": {
   "topImageOffset": -83,
   "leftImageOffset": 0
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: This appears to be exactly what I want.  Checking it out now.

Comment: This is very handy:  https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/
I never got either way to work yet, but think I'm close now that I have the full list of api end points :)

Comment: Hope you guys see this comment. The above request only return a YouTube channel if it's under **Others** label of the Links. If it's in YouTube label, it won't appear on the results. So it only works for handful of channels out of like thousand accounts. Is there another way of doing this that returns every channels associated with given G+ ID?

Comment: An admirable answer, but it's not reliable and it doesn't provide YouTube channel IDs. My answer uses the YouTube API, to reliably load all channels that pertain to a Google Authenticated user.

Answer (score 5):

As per the Google YouTube API [channels list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) documentation, you can get a JSON response containing all the YouTube channels that pertain to a specific Google user.

**Step One**

Obviously you need to ensure that you use OAuth 2.0 to login to the Google Developer API (ensuring that you use to YouTube scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube). This is because you need an `access_token`, in order to load user specific data.

**Step Two**

The [channels list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) API can find channels via: username, channel ID, etc... An ID string is **not** required however. Instead you can set the `mine` boolean parameter to `true`, in order to get the YouTube channels owned by a particular Google user (you don't have to specify the ID of the Google user, because the `access_token` lets YouTube know which user is attempting to load the data).

In order to use the API, make a request using the following URL (replacing 'YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE' your `access_token`):

> https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cstatistics&mine=true&access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE

Here is the `JSON` response that you'll get:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
 "etag": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#channel",
   "etag": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
   "id": "YOUTUBE_CHANNEL_ID",
   "snippet": {
    "title": "Daniel Sadjadian",
    "description": "I’m Daniel Sadjadian - Car enthusiast, computer programmer & entrepreneur running my own business. I live life to the max and try my best to get the most out of each day. Every moment counts :)",
    "customUrl": "danielsadjadian",
    "publishedAt": "2013-11-09T19:47:41.000Z",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/-EF0LibpIsEY/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/n0mUHQnyfkc/s88-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg"
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/-EF0LibpIsEY/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/n0mUHQnyfkc/s240-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg"
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/-EF0LibpIsEY/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/n0mUHQnyfkc/s240-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg"
     }
    },
    "localized": {
     "title": "Daniel Sadjadian",
     "description": "I’m Daniel Sadjadian - Car enthusiast, computer programmer & entrepreneur running my own business. I live life to the max and try my best to get the most out of each day. Every moment counts :)"
    },
    "country": "GB"
   },
   "contentDetails": {
    "relatedPlaylists": {
     "likes": "LLXQYiggNxzVJ51ofKyG2ZUg",
     "favorites": "FLXQYiggNxzVJ51ofKyG2ZUg",
     "uploads": "UUXQYiggNxzVJ51ofKyG2ZUg",
     "watchHistory": "HL",
     "watchLater": "WL"
    }
   },
   "statistics": {
    "viewCount": "30305",
    "commentCount": "0",
    "subscriberCount": "100",
    "hiddenSubscriberCount": false,
    "videoCount": "25"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

The `JSON` response includes details about the user's channel including the channel ID. You can then use the channel ID (in conjunction with other YouTube APIs) to load the channel videos/playlists/activities/etc...

Comment: Hello, I know that this comment was posted long time ago but do you know if it is still possible to find someones youtube channel based on informations from his google-sign-in ?