# Youtube channels from google+ id

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, google-api, google-plus

With the youtube API, I can find my google+ id from my channel id

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?id=...&part=contentDetails&key=...

Is there a way to find my list of channels using my g+ id ?

I've looked at this question [Google API: Find a Users YouTube Channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14860782/google-api-find-a-users-youtube-channel) and it seems that https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/...?key=... should return the list it but mine is pretty much empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't any way to get a channel from someone else's G+ ID.

You can only get authorized user's channel (even when they sign in with G+), simple by calling [channels->list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) with parameter [mine](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list#mine)=true.