# Get YouTube Channel ID from associated Google User ID with API

Tags: api, youtube, google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I've hit a wall in a project I'm attempting to build ...

OK -So I am trying to build an internal 'YouTube Playlist Share' dashboard - So people within my domain can see YouTube playlists they and co-workers have created.  The basic framework I've set up executes properly  for the authenticated user (displaying playlists they've created, editing them, creating new ones, etc) but I cannot figure out a way to retrieve other members YouTube information.

I can successfully retrieve a list of users within our domain leveraging the "gapi.client.directory.users.list" function (this returns userID and email) but cannot for-the-life-of-me figure out a way to plug that data into the YouTube API and get information from there.

Does anyone have any insight on how to pull YouTube Channel data based on Google User ID - They have to be connected somehow ... right !?

Will gladly post code if it helps, but this is more of an API functionality question.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Based on the available api request response, I can't see any direct connection between a google account and youtube. The only connection i see is between youtube and google plus where in you can check whether the youtube channel is linked to [google plus](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#contentDetails.googlePlusUserId) and retrieve the google plus id.

But I saw a similar question below which might help you go further

[Google API: Find a Users YouTube Channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14860782/google-api-find-a-users-youtube-channel).

It uses [google plus api](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people/get) to get the details of a user and get the youtube url linked to that account.